# Windows mobile program without form

Tags: forms, windows-mobile

Is there a way to have a windows mobile app without a form?

I'm writing a small program which is intercepting SMS messages, but I don't want the program to pop up every time it receives a message (which it does right now).
any way to have the sms processed in the background instead of popping up the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  Don't create a Form in the Main entry point of the application and it won't have a Form.

Comment: But then I would need to multi-thread, letting the main thread wait for some event to end the program, since I don't have a form to handle events (sms interception, timer)?

Comment: Of course.  How else would you propose to do this?  You can always create your own message pump (the Smart Device Framework has a Form-less pump as well) but you have to have some sort of loop to keep the app from exiting the entry method.